# Questions asking for materials or links

Tags: discussion

I believe that reading vintage codes or codes or papers where some idea was introduced for the first time will expose the concept in its simplest form and hence will lead to clearer and deeper understanding as it will be free of profuse interspersing of many libraries and framework and hence we can visualize at the utmost depth.

Are questions asking for links to some old papers or source codes, if some other user is having it in their repository is encouraged or stymied ?

Comment: There is [tag:reference-request], but you'll have to be more specific. Asking "what paper can I read on AI?" is too broad and will be closed; "where can I find the original statement of theorem 7 in Example Book by John Doe?"  would be a  good question.

Comment: Asking for links to code is probably/typically off-topic here. Also, see https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1306/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/473/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/660/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/755 for discussions related to your question.